# How to delete the Nth line of a bunch of files

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a set of 30+ files containing key-value pairs or translated strings in the format:

```
key=some text
```

Sometimes I want to delete some keys from these files and what I do is open one of them, locate the line that contains the key I want to delete (e.g. line 310) and then manually delete that line from the other files. Keys in these files are sorted alphabetically, hence if a the key appears on line 310 of a file, then it appears in line 310 of every other file.

What would be an easy way to delete a line by number (e.g. line 310) from a bunch of files?

Comment: To delete line 310 from a bunch of files you can do `sed -i.bak '310d' files*`

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on user000001 idea, here's a more general approach.

```
    sed -i.bak "$(grep -n keyTarget keyFile|sed 's/:.*$//')d;" files*
```

Assuming your sed supports the -i option (most do).

You could even put this in a script and so than rather than editing `keyTarget` each time, you would just use a command-line parameter by use instead of `keyTarget` , `${@}` .

To confirm this will work as you expect, confirm you only get one line number back from the internal part

```
grep -n keyTarget keyFile|sed 's/:.*$//'
```

Until you're very certain that you never find a case where line numbers are off, I would save the whole collections of files to a backup dir.

Having the script support editing multiple targets gets risker, but could be done . If you like this and it works for you needs, but you could use multiple targets, post a new question, showing where you are stuck.

IHTH

Answer (score 4):

```
sed -i '' '310d' file1 file2 ...
```

will delete line 310 from all files specified keeping no backup copies.
The full procedure as defined by you goes like this:

```
KEY=mykey
FILE1=myfile
ALL_FILES="file1 file2 ..."
sed -i '' $(grep -n "^$KEY=" $FILE1 | head -1 | sed -E 's/^([0-9]+):.*/\1/')d $ALL_FILES
```

but a simpler approach is:

```
KEY=mykey
ALL_FILES="file1 file2 ..."
sed -i '' "/^$KEY=/d" $ALL_FILES
```

which means "delete every line starting with 'mykey=' from $ALL_FILES keeping no backup copies".

Comment: yes, actually this is a better idea, as then you don't have to worry about "do all files **really** have the same value on line #310?". Good luck to all.